Kaniko caching for multistage Docker builds
I have a multistage docker file. It has a parent stage (that installs the dev dependencies) and a child stage (that takes parent stage as the base) and install all test related dependencies.
I have 2 different build stages one that builds the parent image and the other that builds the child image. Both are pushed to gitlab registry. (commit_id and functional_commit_id). Kaniko caching is enabled here.
I want that while building the child stage - kaniko cache to pick to cached commands from the parent image as well as the child image.
How can one do that?
I have verified both images are pushed to gitlab registry and can verify that the layers are cached via logs. But while building the test image : only cached layers in the parent image are being used, not the child image
